# Binding OData Service to view

Tags: sapui5

I want to bind oData services to SAPUI5 view but not bind. How to fix this problem?

tes.view.xml

```
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
        controllerName="tes.tes">
    <Page title="Title">
        <content>
            <Label text="Hai dunia!"></Label>

            <List
                headerText="Products"
                items="{
                    path: '/DATA'
                    }" >
                    <StandardListItem
                        title="{NAME}"
                        counter="{DESC}"/>
            </List>
        </content>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

tes.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define([
        'jquery.sap.global',
        'sap/m/MessageToast',
        'sap/ui/core/Fragment',
        'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
        'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'
    ], function(jQuery, MessageToast, Fragment, Controller, JSONModel) {
    "use strict";

    var CController = Controller.extend("tes.tes", {

        onInit : function () {
            var model = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("http://192.168.78.23:8000/Tes/WebContent/tes/data.xsodata", false);
            console.log(model);
            var model2 = new JSONModel(model);
            this.getView().setModel(model2);

        }

    });
    return CController;

});
```

data.xsodata

```
service namespace "tes" {
    "HANATES"."USER" as "DATA"; 
}
```

project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

data:

[image: JSON Data]

Data not bind to view SAPUI5.

Thanks.

Bobby

Comment: i already used path "/d/results" or "/DATA" but still not bind to view

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with your models:

1. `var model = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("http://192.168.78.23:8000/Tes/WebContent/tes/data.xsodata", false);` - This step is right. You are creating a oData Model.
2. `var model2 = new JSONModel(model);` - This here is a problem. JSONModel constructor will accept either the URL where to load the JSON from or a JS object but you are passing an OData Model instance.  This step will not fetch the data from oDataModel.
3. `this.getView().setModel(model2);' - Change this to` this.getView().setModel(model);` - Make ODataModel as your default model to view ( Since you have done the binding - /data in your view.)

NOTE: If you want to bind a JSONModel to your view, then :

1. Call ODataModel.read method to fetch data from Server.
2. in Sucess handler of oDataModel.read, copy the data to JSON Model.
3. Bind the respective JSON Model to view.

LINK: for OdataModel read method https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#read

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: oh. before I code this, I not try with json.. I try with :
var model = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("http://192.168.78.23:8000/Tes/WebContent/tes/data.xsodata", false);
this.getView().setModel(model);

but not fix this problem. thanks

Comment: try binding view with : /DATA/results. I wonder why results array has been created as you have no passed any filter parameters. :s.

Comment: still not bind to view with path "/DATA/results"

Comment: have you set data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax='complex' in boostrap of sapui5 in index.html ( since you are using path to bind the List) ?